# Msg 329, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference

Tags: sql-server, database

```
Declare procursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CLAIMNO from RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO
DECLARE @myyear Integer
Declare @provar varchar(22)

open procursor

fetch next from procursor into @provar

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
SET @myyear = (SELECT 
CASE
WHEN CONVERT(INTEGER,BTHDAT) = 0 THEN 0 //if the birthdate is 0
WHEN  datepart(DY,convert(date, BTHDAT)) > datepart(DY,'2015/07/01') THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, convert(date, BTHDAT),'2015/07/01') - 1 //DY of a persons date is greater than 2015/01/01 then subtract the year by one
ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR,convert(date, BTHDAT),'2015/07/01') 
END
from RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO WHERE CLAIMNO = @provar)


SELECT  SERVICE_GROUP, SERVICE_CATEGORY,
CASE
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 0 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 5 THEN 'Early Child'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 6 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 12 THEN 'Child'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 13 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 17 THEN 'Adolescent'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 18 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 21 THEN 'Transitional'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 22 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 64 THEN 'Adult'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 >= 65 THEN 'Geriatric'
ELSE '0'  
END AS Age_desc,
SUM(CONVERT(MONEY, TOPAY)) AS PAID_AMT    
FROM RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO
WHERE SERVICE_FY = '2016' and DISTYP = 'P' AND CLAIMNO = @provar 
GROUP BY 
SERVICE_GROUP,SERVICE_CATEGORY,
CASE
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 0 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 5 THEN 'Early Child'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 6 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 12 THEN 'Child'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 13 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 17 THEN 'Adolescent'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 18 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 21 THEN 'Transitional'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 <= 22 AND @myyear - 2015 >= 64 THEN 'Adult'
WHEN @myyear - 2015 >= 65 THEN 'Geriatric'
ELSE '0'  
END 

fetch next from procursor into @provar 

END

CLOSE procursor
```

This is my code. When I run this I get the following error
**Msg 329, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference.**

And also can we use %rowtype in MS sql server.?
Can someone help me please

Comment: So you [adked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655470/ms-sql-server-assigning-a-date-to-a-variable) and didn't say anything and now have a new error... if you would elaborate on the first question in that post it would help--and you need to deallocate that cursor at the end. And // isn't how you comment out something in SSMS / SQL Server and %rowtype is ORACLE--row_number() is similar but you are so vague.

Comment: @scsimon why? it's easier to just keep making new SO posts and have users guess. It's like playing 20 questions!

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here? There are so many thing going on here that need to be fixed....

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that...

> **Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference.**

The `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` is not referencing any columns. It is instead using a variable (`@myyear`), because of this the value will be the same for every record and so it does nothing for the `GROUP BY` and so `SQL` assumed you made a mistake.

There is a lot going on in your query, so it is hard to tell what you are really trying to do. It seems that you want to get the total `PAID_AMT` for each `SERVICE_GROUP`, `SERVICE_CATEGORY`, `Age_desc`.

To start I am going to replace your variable `@myyear` with just a column of a `SELECT` statement. I'm not sure what you are trying to do when calculating that value, so in my example I'm just going to use the `DATEPART(yyyy, ..)`. You could easily replace this with your calculation though. So that will look like this..

```
SELECT 
    SERVICE_GROUP, 
    SERVICE_CATEGORY,
    BirthYear = DATEPART(yyyy, BTHDAT),
    TOPAY
FROM RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO
```

This can be selected in a new query either from a subquery or a CTE to cleanly get the different descriptions. Notice that I have flipped the comparators, e.g. instead of `value <= 0 AND value >= 5` I have `value >= 0 AND value <= 5` and that I let the else case be for ages `>= 65` instead of having `ELSE '0'`.

```
;WITH Claims AS (
    SELECT 
        SERVICE_GROUP, 
        SERVICE_CATEGORY,
        BirthYear = DATEPART(yyyy, BTHDAT)
    FROM RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO
)

SELECT
    SERVICE_GROUP,
    SERVICE_CATEGORY,
    Age_Desc = CASE
        WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 0 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 5 THEN 'Early Child'
        WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 6 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 12 THEN 'Child'
        WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 13 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 17 THEN 'Adolescent'
        WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 18 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 21 THEN 'Transitional'
        WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 22 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 64 THEN 'Adult'
        ELSE 'Senior' END,
    TOPAY
FROM Claims
```

Now all that is left to do is `GROUP` and `SUM`. Once again this can be done using a subquery or CTE.

```
;WITH Claims AS (
    SELECT 
        SERVICE_GROUP, 
        SERVICE_CATEGORY,
        BirthYear = DATEPART(yyyy, BTHDAT)
    FROM RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO
),
Claims_Categories AS (
    SELECT
        SERVICE_GROUP,
        SERVICE_CATEGORY,
        Age_Desc = CASE
            WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 0 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 5 THEN 'Early Child'
            WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 6 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 12 THEN 'Child'
            WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 13 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 17 THEN 'Adolescent'
            WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 18 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 21 THEN 'Transitional'
            WHEN BirthYear - 2015 >= 22 AND BirthYear - 2015 <= 64 THEN 'Adult'
            ELSE 'Senior' END,
        TOPAY
    FROM Claims 
)

SELECT
    SERVICE_GROUP,
    SERVICE_CATEGORY,
    Age_Desc,
    SUM(CONVERT(MONEY, TOPAY))
FROM Claims_Categories
GROUP BY SERVICE_GROUP, SERVICE_CATEGORY, AGE_DESC
```

And that's it! No cursor needed. One last improvement I would do is get rid of the hardcoded `2015`, instead lets use a variable. For this example I'm just going to use the current year, but depending on your use case you could also pass it as a Stored Procedure parameter.

```
DECLARE @CurrentYear INT = DATEPART(yyyy, GETUTCDATE())
```

Then you just use `@CurrentYear` instead of `2015`.

```
DECLARE @CurrentYear INT = DATEPART(yyyy, GETUTCDATE())

;WITH Claims AS (
    SELECT 
        SERVICE_GROUP, 
        SERVICE_CATEGORY,
        BirthYear = DATEPART(yyyy, BTHDAT)
    FROM RPT_CLAIM_MD_COMBO
),
Claims_Categories AS (
    SELECT
        SERVICE_GROUP,
        SERVICE_CATEGORY,
        Age_Desc = CASE
            WHEN BirthYear - @CurrentYear >= 0 AND BirthYear - @CurrentYear <= 5 THEN 'Early Child'
            WHEN BirthYear - @CurrentYear >= 6 AND BirthYear - @CurrentYear <= 12 THEN 'Child'
            WHEN BirthYear - @CurrentYear >= 13 AND BirthYear - @CurrentYear <= 17 THEN 'Adolescent'
            WHEN BirthYear - @CurrentYear >= 18 AND BirthYear - @CurrentYear <= 21 THEN 'Transitional'
            WHEN BirthYear - @CurrentYear >= 22 AND BirthYear - @CurrentYear <= 64 THEN 'Adult'
            ELSE 'Senior' END,
        TOPAY
    FROM Claims 
)

SELECT
    SERVICE_GROUP,
    SERVICE_CATEGORY,
    Age_Desc,
    SUM(CONVERT(MONEY, TOPAY))
FROM Claims_Categories
GROUP BY SERVICE_GROUP, SERVICE_CATEGORY, AGE_DESC
```